# How to implement web camera for video conferencing in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a asp web application for video conferencing, how i can implement this?
Thanks...

Comment: There are open source video conferencing solutions that can be the starting point for your application but they are not in asp.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a jQuery plugin for that.

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, the better support for such issue was implemented within Silverlight technology. As start point I can suggest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602282%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

It is possible to implement your Silverlight into ASP.NET like was described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135987.aspx)